# Replace whitespace after 2 char word

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have question, how to replace whitespace between 2 or 1 char word and any string with &nbsp. I mean something like:

```
Cart is protecting
on garder
```

To:

```
Cart is&nbspprotecting
on&nbspgarder
```

I try to use this:`preg_replace("/[.{1,2}\s+.+]/g", "&nbsp;", $string);`
but it's replace every whitespace

Comment: to get rid of the &nbsp; problem use html_entity_decode on the string before you apply the regex-pattern. This of course does not solve the complete problem but a part of it and it makes the pattern easier to formulate

Comment: why doesnt `cart is` become`cart&nbsp` . please clarify

Comment: `'/\b(\w{1,2})\s+(?=\w)/g'   --- "$1&nbsp;" `

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below regex.

```
preg_replace('~(?<!\S)(\S{1,2})\h+~', '\1&nbsp', $string);
```

`(?<!\S)` negative look-behind asserts that the match won't be preceded by a non-space character.

`(\S{1,2})` Captures one or two non-space character.

`\h+` matches one or more horizontal white-space characters.

**OR**

Add a positive lookahead to check that the matched spaces are followed by a non-space character or not.

```
preg_replace('~(?<!\S)(\S{1,2})\h+(?=\S)~', '\1&nbsp', $string);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zB3hI5/5)